# Local admin in Win7

Tags: windows-7

How can I access machines in the network as local admin in Windows 7?

Comment: Have you tried?  Like have you typed in `.\localadminaccount` or `machinename\localadminaccount`???  Just because it tries to make you connect as a domain user by default, doesn't mean that's the only way to connect. :/

Answer (score 4):

Try typing in `.\localadminaccount` or `machinename\localadminaccount` in the username field of the credentials dialogue that pops up. Just because it tries to make you connect as a domain user by default, doesn't mean that's the only way to connect. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The local administrator account is disabled by default under 7. Best practice would be to leave it as such.

If you really want a local admin accounts you can create an accounts  set passwords, etc - with group policy preferences as well as assign the new account to the local administrators group.

The better practice would be to create a new domain group - say 'desktop admins' - and assign this group to the local administrators group. Put your domain accounts into this group to provide access.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable this behaviour by adding the registry key descibed at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016.

Basically:

Under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Set:

LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy = DWORD 0x1